# How can I execute a MIPSEB-LE ECOFF executable file?

Tags: assembly, mips, executable, disassembly, steganography

I extracted a file that I have found to be a MIPSEB-LE ECOFF executable file in a part of a steganography challenge. When I run "file executablefile" i get "executablefile: MIPSEB-LE ECOFF executable not stripped".  I am having quite a bit of trouble researching on the internet how to go about running such an executable, and I would really appreciate any guidance in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: You could try to use `objconv` to convert it into an ELF binary.  However, note that if the program was written for another operating system, it's unlikely that it's going to run.

Comment: Also, the desire to execute an untrusted binary should not be your first thought in the reverse engineering business. The program inside can be outright malicious. You should always disassemble and understand its basic static properties first. Then you may decide to run it inside a simulator/emulator/virtual machine. Note that even using a VM does not guarantee 100% safeness these days — such environments can also have vulnerabilities which can be targeted from the outside of a VM.

Comment: Also be aware the `file` tool itself may report the file not accurately, maybe it is cleverly engineered x86 binary masking as MIPS ECOFF, but would execute even on x86, etc... It's lot more likely correct and really MIPS ECOFF, but doing some basic validation (checking if the file headers make sense and first instruction look to be MIPS and reasonable) sounds like good next step. `file` is often checking just some regex pattern or few bytes in the header to report particular MIME types, so with complex formats it may be deceived if you are "creative" enough with building the file.

Comment: `s/outside/inside/` in my previous comment; that is, a code **inside** a virtual machine can sometimes attach the virtual machine monitor and/or host system.

Answer (score 4):

ECOFF [seems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_executable_file_formats) to be a variant of COFF that was used in Ultrix, Tru64 UNIX, IRIX, and possibly Linux/MIPS. This [page](https://opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/cctools-590/file/magdir/sgi) for `file` patterns also states that it is format specific for Silicon Graphics and Dell Ultrix systems. The same file states that it has to use the big-endian data convention.

Qemu has [basic support](https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/QEMU) of MIPS CPU chips variants, but there is not much support for SGI OSes. [Here](https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Emulators) is the list of simulators that support MIPS, and at least a few of them report to run IRIX.

My suggestion is that before you start trying different simulators and OSes for them, which would be an innumerable amount of combinations, you should do a deeper static analysis of the file. Understand if it is packed/encrypted or not, what system calls it does which would be a good indication of what OS it is written for and what it can do, what human-readable strings it contains etc.

Comment: Thanks, do you know any good resources where i can learn about  extracting such data from an executable?

Comment: @ColbyMorgan: `objdump -d` to disassemble it (with a build of binutils that supports MIPS), and start reading the disassembly to see what kind of stuff it's doing.  @fuz's suggestion to use `objconv` or `objcopy` may help if `objdump` doesn't understand the file format.

Comment: @ColbyMorgan this is a more general question of "how do I reverse a program?". Use dedicated tools for that, such as [radare2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radare2) (free) or IDA pro (costs $$$), or general-purpose tools such as `objdump` (does not work well with code that was written to conceal its own behavior). If you are a bookworm like me, reading a book "IDA Pro book" [link](https://nostarch.com/idapro2.htm) can help understanding basic terminology and approaches